# Importing XML and Skipping Errors (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, xml, error-handling

I have a CRON job that runs each night to update our stock system (from an external source) via multiple XML files.

However, as is occasionally the case, errors appear in the XML (nothing I can do about this - 3rd party provides this).

When an error does occur, the script comes to a stop and no more files are processed. Is there a way that if an error is encountered, the remaining files are still imported?

Here is my code:

```
<?php include 'connect.php'; 


$sql = "DELETE FROM stock WHERE allow_keep!='1'";
mysql_query($sql);

//clear stock table then loop through and add all active users


$query = "SELECT * from users where active='1'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 


$xml = simplexml_load_file(“users/XML_FILE_”.$row['id'].".xml");

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
{


$myquery="REPLACE into stock set 
StockID='" . $child->stockid . 
"', Make='" . addslashes($child->make) . 
"', Model='" . addslashes($child->model) . 
"', image='" . $child->image_url_1 . 
"', details='" . addslashes($child->description) . 
"', price='" . $child->price . 
"'";

$result2=mysql_query($myquery) or die(mysql_error());   




 }

}


?>
```

Appreciate any help I can get with this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's simplexml the one interrupting the process, just tell it to [deal with errors internally](http://php.net//manual/es/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) instead of outputting them

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xml = simplexml_load_file(“users/XML_FILE_”.$row['id'].".xml");
if($xml) {
    // format is fine, try to load it.
} else {
    // leave something in your error log or something
}
```

if it's mysql, then you can wrap your replace query in a try / catch block.

BTW, don't use mysql functions. Use mysqli or (better yet) PDO functions. If you're afraid of the learning curve, start with PDO::exec, it's not the most elegant part of PDO but it's practically a drop in replacement if you're used to manually make queries with variable interpolation.

Try to aim to build prepared queries in the mid term, it will pay off tenfold.